# Vue.js/vuex getters error before state rendered

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Using webpack vue template and vuex.I have a mutation in my store

```
const mutations = {
addWeekDataList(state, a) {
    state.weekDataList = a;
},}
```

which is being committed inside an ajax request inside a component

```
axios.get('URL').then(function (response) {
let weekDataList = _.values(response);
that.$store.commit('addWeekDataList', weekDataList);});
```

I then have a getter in my store

```
const getters = {
getWeekRunData: state => {
    return state.weekDataList[state.currentWeek].filter(activity => activity.type === 'Run' );
},
}
```

Which are called inside a component's computed property

```
computed: {
    weekRunDataTime: function() {
        return Utils.convertSecsToHrsMins(Utils.addFields(this.weekRunData, 'moving_time'));
    },
    ...mapGetters({
        weekRunData: 'getWeekRunData',
    }),
},
```

There are no errors so far, the computed properties return their data when it's ready. However as soon as i do the following inside the component template I get an error...

```
{{ weekRunDataTime }}
TypeError: state.weekDataList[state.currentWeek] is undefined
```

The computed property, and then the {{ weekRunDataTime }}, will eventually render but the error still shows initially, how do i get around this? Ensuring the getters only run once the data is available?

Comment: what is `state`? Normally to access a vuex `store` something like `this.$store.state...` is the syntax.

Comment: Hi @AmreshVenugopal the `state` within the getter and mutation is inside the store, so can reference directly.

Comment: Sorry, that was a big mistake at my part at reading the question. What is the default value of `state.weekDataList` ?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal the initial default is an empty array. Which is replaced by a full array after the ajax. Hence why `arr[0]` woudl be undefined. No issues with data or their rendering, just with the getters running before this ajax call has created the full state. I initially thought there might be some kind of critical rule to ensure something is loaded, or perhaps I'm doing things wrong, but had no luck.

Comment: As you have noticed it is failing because there is no data loaded yet. You can have an if else or ternary to prevent the code to execute if there is no data.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal that's worked and removes the initial error! I initially had a sample data set to solve this issue but I think your solution is better, thank you!

Comment: I'll just add it as an answer for the record

Answer (score 2):

The error is because `state.weekDataList` isn't loaded so `state.weekDataList[0]` would be undefined. 
I came across two solutions, once of which was from @AmreshVenugopal. One was to add a sample data set into the array and the second, and most preferred, was to add an `if` statement into the getter, so that it only loads once the data is loaded. Everything now loads fine with no errors.

```
const getters = {
getWeekRunData: state => {
    if(state.weekDataList.length) return state.weekDataList[state.currentWeek].filter(activity => activity.type === 'Run' );
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding initial data will resolve the issue

```
const state = {
      user: something
    };
```